# Spring integration - how to initiate a database transaction on the flow?

Tags: spring-integration

I have an integration flow that sinks DML queries at the end.

I have a config file to log transactions:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction.interceptor=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction.support=DEBUG
```

The `sinkSql` method is called but there is no transaction log.

If I just call `e.transactional(true)` I get an error because there are two transaction managers (one is from the source database).

```
@Bean(name = SYBASE_TRAN_MANAGER)
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier(SYBASE_DS) final DataSource sybaseDataSource) {
    DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
    dataSourceTransactionManager.setDataSource(sybaseDataSource);
    return dataSourceTransactionManager;
}

@Bean
public TransactionInterceptor sybaseTransactionInterceptor(@Qualifier(SYBASE_TRAN_MANAGER) final TransactionManager tm) {
    return new TransactionInterceptorBuilder(true)
            .transactionManager(tm)
            .isolation(Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
            .propagation(Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
            .readOnly(false)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sinkSqlFlow(final TransactionInterceptor sybaseTransactionInterceptor) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(SYBASE_SINK_SQL)
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL, SYBASE_ERROR))
            .handle(this::sinkSql, e -> e.transactional(sybaseTransactionInterceptor))
            .get();
}

public void sinkSql(final Message<?> message) {
    //jdbcTemplate logic here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why is the question since `TransactionAspectSupport` does just this plain fallback if we don't provide an explicit `TransactionManager` to the interceptor configuration:

```
if (defaultTransactionManager == null) {
                defaultTransactionManager = this.beanFactory.getBean(TransactionManager.class);
                this.transactionManagerCache.putIfAbsent(
                        DEFAULT_TRANSACTION_MANAGER_KEY, defaultTransactionManager);
            }
```

where that `getBean(Class aClass)` indeed is going to fail if several beans of type is present in the application context. So, what you did so far with a `sybaseTransactionInterceptor` bean definition is OK.

You can use an overloaded Java DSL method though:

```
/**
 * Specify a {@link TransactionInterceptor} {@link Advice} with the provided
 * {@code PlatformTransactionManager} and default
 * {@link org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.DefaultTransactionAttribute}
 * for the {@link MessageHandler}.
 * @param transactionManager the {@link TransactionManager} to use.
 * @param handleMessageAdvice the flag to indicate the target {@link Advice} type:
 * {@code false} - regular {@link TransactionInterceptor}; {@code true} -
 * {@link org.springframework.integration.transaction.TransactionHandleMessageAdvice}
 * extension.
 * @return the spec.
 */
public S transactional(TransactionManager transactionManager, boolean handleMessageAdvice) {
```

Although having your sink contract as `void sinkSql(final Message<?> message)`, there is no need in that `true`: the transaction is going to be applied for a `handleMessage()` method which is really the end of your flow anyway.

Comment: Using this suggested overload didn't work, but putting `sinkSql` on another class and annotating it with @Transacional did.

Comment: It cannot be. See that method implementation. It does something similar what you have so far with the `sybaseTransactionInterceptor`. I agree that there is no way to setup other options you have over  there, but that didn't sound like a question from your original concern. So, how it does not work? What are those symptoms?

Comment: I must have done something wrong. Tried again just passing `e -> e.transactional(tm)` where `tm` is the injected `TransactionManager` and it works. Thanks.